# Generating Box Auth code for OAuth2 in programmatic way

Tags: java, box-api, box, oauth-2.0

I am developing a Java standalone application which uses Java box sdk to access my box account to access files stored there.

I am using `OAuth2` for authentication to box account. Current steps are:

1. I configure the redirect URI using `developers/services`.
2. I use
   **https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[client id]&state=authenticated**
   in the browser to authorise access to my box account. This is a manual steps where I have intervene to give authorisation to my account.
3. Once I authorise it will redirect me to next page which have auth_code embed in the url
4. I retrieve the auth_code(boxAuthCode) from the url and paste in the application like

   ```
   BoxAPIConnection box_connection = new BoxAPIConnection(boxId, boxSecret, *boxAuthCode*);
   ```

Application is executed within 30 sec (AuthCode expires within 30 sec) to generate refresh_token. The refresh token is persisted and is used in subsequent request to setup connection with box account.

```
box_connection  = new BoxAPIConnection(boxId, boxSecret, tokens.get("Auth_Token"),  tokens.get("Refresh_Token"));
```

Although step 2,3,4 is one time activity for a box account but I have to intervene manually to generate auth_code and then execute the application within 30 sec to get refresh token. It become really troublesome if I want to change the box account frequently.

Is there a flexible and programmatic way to handle this.I do not want to intervene manually, so if I want to access another box account it is sufficient for me to change `boxId` and `boxSecret` in the application and configure redirect uri for box account and application should be able to take care of steps 2,3 and 4.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Box support doesn't seem to understand this at all and keeps redirecting me to the same OAuth documentation page...